# TeamCity LDAP not able to log into UI anymore after update

Tags: teamcity

The LDAP settings were messed up on my TeamCity instance in such a way that LDAP users were no longer able to log in. (basically teamcity.options.users.synchronize.deleteUsers=true was set to true).

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using the TeamCity built in functionality to roll back the changes and get our users back, but the reason that I wanted to post this question and more specifically the answer was that TeamCity has a feature called a "SuperUser" https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Super+User which (assuming you haven't disabled it) you can use to log into your TeamCity instance and view the pieces of the UI.

I wasn't able to find this with any quick google searches, so I was hoping this QandA might help other people debug and their TeamCity instances when they get in a jam.

This is just another tool in your toolbelt kind of thing.